# Adding System.Web.Optimization to VS2012 Project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, system.web.optimization

I downloaded VS2012 Express for Web today just to mess with it.  Did a tutorial that was on the ASP.Net website.  Then I decided to start my own project and start it with an Empty site.  This way I can see how/why some things were added and what they do.  When trying to add:

```
@Styles.Render...
```

I came across the issue of not having Bundles defined which means that I need to add a reference to System.Web.Optimization.  However, when I go to add a Reference, it's not in the list.  When I go to "add" a reference in the tutorial I did, it's not in that list either.  How does one add System.Web.Optimization to your project?  It's obviously installed on my machine since I used it in the other application, but I didn't have to add it (was done when the project was created).  The project that was created for the tutorial was from a ASP.Net MVC 4 template (Internet Application).  When I started my own, I still used the ASP.Net MVC 4 template, but Empty instead.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization is the nuget package that you need to add

Comment: Ok, that worked.  This is my first time using 2012, used to only adding references and dlls, not packages.

Comment: Yeah with the internet application it has ~35 packages it installs where as with empty it is about ~10